# Share Windows connection through ethernet

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop, ethernet

I have a Windows 10 desktop computer connected to internet using a WiFi card. And then I have my laptop on which I'd like to play games remotely from the computer (using for example the steam remote play) Issue is that using the same WiFi is unstable.

I was then thinking about sharing the Windows 10 connection with my laptop with ethernet so that they end up on the same local network and the remote play would work without any issue. The network access would be done using the WiFi card of my  desktop computer.

Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/share-internet-connection-windows-ethernet-wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

You could always try doing an RDP connection, however if your wifi is unstable you are most likely going to run into connection issues. Not to mention using a remote connection produces a lag unless you have some wicked fast internet and some serious graphic cards. Even then I don’t know if you would have much luck.

Comment: When I say that wifi is unstable, I mean that when I use wifi (even with a dedicated router to stream from desktop to client) I sometimes glitches a bit. Using cable would resolve this issue as my laptop would be connected to me desktop with a single cable